# Improve precision on numpy narrays

Tags: python, numpy, mathematical-optimization, mpmath, numerical-stability

I have written this optimization procedure using numpy where I have to perform the following calculation:

[image: formula]

B is a symmetric negative semi-definite matrix and I the identity matrix.
The problem is that the values of B can be too big (>1e25) and when subtracting by the diagonal matrix some elements don't because there is enough precision.
Is there any way to overcome this problem or do I need to rewrite it using another library like mpmath?

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-implement, but the implementation may be simple: change your numeric representation.  Since you didn't specify the base type you're using, or the actual value range (1e25 versus *what*?), I can't make a definite recommendation.

However, note that `numpy` has several types with greater precision, including longdouble (80 bits), float96, and float128.  If you need more than 128 bits (38 digits of precision), then `mpmath` is the way to go.